# @RestController does not work, it still return me a jsp page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class CommodityController {

    @RequestMapping("test.htm")
    public String test() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Spring version:

```
<org.springframework.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
```

Still not working:

[image]

Can I use `@RestController` like this?

Comment: What behaviour do you expect? You should check your `InternalResourceViewResolver` bean settings in your Spring config. Can you show it?

Comment: you need to post your spring config

Comment: Has been solved, I add <mvc:annotation-driven/> to dispatch-servlet.xml,